# Unset session expire in SailsJS - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, session, sails.js, node-webkit

I am creating an application in which, I have a authentication page wherein, I need the session to be set on login, but it should not expire unless the user logs out or closes the application. Right now the session is getting expired automatically even though I haven't set any session expire.

Please help me find a solution. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `config/session.js`. Here's an example:

```
  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * Set the session cookie expire time The maxAge is set by milliseconds,    *
  * the example below is for 24 hours                                        *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/

  cookie: {
     maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  },
```

So, you should be able to put the cookie value to some very long time, like 10 years or whatever else you like. I think you can also make it never expire.

Comment: Okay. Will try that. Thank you. I also found that if you give maxAge as **null**, the session will not expire. But not sure about that.

Comment: It's relatively simple to test it.

Comment: Is there any method to test session rather  than keeping my app opne?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You mean like an unit test or something? You can create a session, then check in your session store what's the validity of that key, right?
Or manually? Inspect the session/cookie in the Resources tab of Chrome console and see when does it expire?

Comment: What attribute is given in the tab to check that? When i checked my resources tab i found it empty. Nothing was there.

Comment: Not sure now, by default I think it's under cookies?